# Can a woocommerce hook alter the UI of a website?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, events

I was wondering if there is a way to make a woocommerce hook that alters the UI of a website. For example, if a user wants to purchase an item it should provide the option of paying with "website points" instead of visa by adding a "purchase using points" button or something similar.

Comment: You say "alter the UI", but unless this "purchase using points" button is entirely decorative, then you're actually asking a whole lot more than adding a button to the UI, you're talking about adding a completely separate currency system.

Comment: Okay so how can I add a separate currency system with for example 100 points being equivalent to 1 dollar and having the option to pay with either points or dollars? @JacobPeattie

Comment: That’s _far_ to big a topic for this site, especially if you’re struggling with adding a button. I’d suggest looking into existing solutions.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a simple UI change, as pointed out above.  If you wanted to develop something I think you would start by creating your own payment gateway.  For example, a buyer could choose to pay for an item by credit card, Paypal or Points.

You can find out more about creating your own gateway [HERE](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/).

Also, there are a couple plugin options that seem pretty close to what you are asking.  Take a look at [THIS](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-points-and-rewards/?utm_campaign=points%20and%20rewards&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=search&utm_term=woocommerce%20points&utm_content=71650237673&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyLDpBRCxARIsAEENsrLuInWoGVWL1ibafgN7lPD4GCM1EFliv0RuwMr8XntxjAMKAgHpyWUaAt2YEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) or [THIS](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-points-and-rewards/).